# how to start puppet master while installing from source code..?

Tags: puppet

I have tried to install from source code, I checked out from github and installed the puppet. I followed the following link to install puppet. In this process I am not able to start the puppet master.

```
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/from_source.html
```

I am getting this following error:
***$: bundle exec puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize --autosign true

Error: Could not run: cannot load such file -- puppet/network/server***

anyhelp would be appreciated ..!!!

Comment: Does the file exist? From the directory, run `ls -l puppet/network/server`. Post whether or not it returns output: the file could be missing which would imply an installation misstep or misconfiguration or it could have restricted permissions that prevent the file from being opened.

Comment: @PatrickM there is no puppet folder in the src directory. But i installed as per the steps in the link which i specified above .
Note:- I dint install puppet using the install.rb file beacuse later i cant upgrade to another version.

Comment: Well it needs to be in `lib/`. The file that is missing is `lib/puppet/network/server.rb`. Are you in the base directory of your git clone when you run the above command?

Comment: @FelixFrank  yes that file exists ..  and i am running the command from the base directory. 
$ ls -la lib/puppet/network/server.rb     
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 815 May 21 15:31 lib/puppet/network/server.rb     
$ pwd    
/root/source/puppet
$ bundle exec puppet master --no-daemonize     
Error: Could not run: cannot load such file -- puppet/network/server    
$cd lib/     
$ pwd    
/root/source/puppet/lib    
$ bundle exec puppet master --no-daemonize     
Error: Could not run: cannot load such file -- puppet/network/server

Comment: Pretty arcane errors. What are your `bundler` and `ruby` versions? Also, check the output of `bundle exec ruby -e 'puts $:'` to see if `/root/source/puppet/lib` is listed **and** not superseded by another Puppet installation. If you have any `puppet` gems installed, you may wish to remove those.

Comment: @FelixFrank bundler-1.9.9 , ruby-2.0 . /root/source/puppet/lib is not present in the output . I did not install any puppet gem on the machine.